# How to save data from session

Tags: php, session

Session from page index to sent to page insert form access just primary key not email to save in another table. please help me. In page index show all code for session

index.php

```
    if(isset($_POST['login']))
{
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $password=md5($_POST['password']);
    $sql ="SELECT EmailAddress,cpassword FROM tblcompany WHERE EmailAddress=:email and cpassword=:password";
    $query= $dbh -> prepare($sql);
    $query-> bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query-> bindParam(':password', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query-> execute();
    $results=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    if($query->rowCount() > 0)
    {
        $_SESSION['alogin']=$_POST['email'];
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'> document.location = 'dashboard.php'; </script>";
    } else{

        echo "<script>alert('Invalid Details');</script>";

    }

}
```

Insert.php

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $RegistrationNumber=$_POST['RegistrationNumber'];
    $ModelCode=$_POST['ModelCode'];
    $DailyHireRate=$_POST['DailyHireRate'];
    $VehicleYear=$_POST['VehicleYear'];
    $VehicleColour=$_POST['VehicleColour'];
    $SeatCapacity=$_POST['SeatCapacity'];
    $vimage1=$_FILES["vimage1"]["name"];
    $vimage2=$_FILES["vimage2"]["name"];
    $vimage3=$_FILES["vimage3"]["name"];
    $companyid=$_SESSION['alogin'];
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["vimage1"]["tmp_name"],"img/vehicleimages/".$_FILES["vimage1"]["name"]);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["vimage2"]["tmp_name"],"img/vehicleimages/".$_FILES["vimage2"]["name"]);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["vimage3"]["tmp_name"],"img/vehicleimages/".$_FILES["vimage3"]["name"]);


    $sql="INSERT INTO tblvehicle(RegistrationNumber,ModelCode,DailyHireRate,VehicleYear,VehicleColour,SeatCapacity,Vimage1,Vimage2,Vimage3,CompanyID) VALUES(:RegistrationNumber,:ModelCode,:DailyHireRate,:VehicleYear,:VehicleColour,:SeatCapacity,:vimage1,:vimage2,:vimage3,:companyid)";
    $query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $query->bindParam(':RegistrationNumber',$RegistrationNumber,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam(':ModelCode',$ModelCode,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam(':DailyHireRate',$DailyHireRate,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam(':VehicleYear',$VehicleYear,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam(':VehicleColour',$VehicleColour,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam(':SeatCapacity',$SeatCapacity,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam(':vimage1',$vimage1,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam(':vimage2',$vimage2,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam(':vimage3',$vimage3,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam(':companyid',$companyid,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->execute();
    $lastInsertId = $dbh->lastInsertId();
    if($lastInsertId)
    {
        $error="Something went wrong. Please try again";
    }
    else
    {
        $msg="Vehicle posted successfully";
    }

}
```

How to access data from session not email but id as primary key to save in another table. UPDATED

Comment: When does `$_SESSION['alogin']=$_POST['email']`? You don't seem to actually set that anywhere after submitting your form. The `$_POST` value only exists after submission.

Comment: I updated the code